# Java - extensive semaphore usage

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

In a server that i write each client handler object include a semaphore for some usages, as there can be many client handlers - I wanted to know if there is a limitation to the number of semaphores a program can hold?

Comment: Java may not have any limitation  but the native OS/hardware might have.

Comment: @Santosh what if the semaphores are being created but most of them are rarely used - does the operation system has a limitation on the number of semaphore instances or the number of threads that are sleeping on the semaphores?

Comment: The operating system does place a limit on number of Semaphore objects that an be created beyond which you cannot have a thread in waiting state. Check out this [link for windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Santosh thanks - care to post it as an answer so i will be able to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system does put a limit on number of semaphore instances that can be created by the application layer. One this limit is reached, no more threads can be in waiting state. This number is specific to the Operating System. Here is [link for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: There is a difference between an OS-Semaphore and a java.util.Semaphore. While there is a limit on the number of semaphores on OS level, a java.util.Semaphore does not block any system ressources (apart from some memory) while not in use (i.e. it is a POJO wrt. special OS-ressources).

Answer (score 0):

A `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` is a standard Java object and as such has the same limitation as every other object in the heap. So, as long as you have enough memory there should be no problem instantiating more `Semaphores`.

I consider it curious that you need such large numbers that you even think about whether this will lead to a problem. Typically, a concurrent program has only a handful of critical sections which have to be secured by different semaphores and most datastructures in Java have Threadsafe alternatives which make your life much easier than manually synchronizing them.

Comment: Most of the time the semaphores not in use but the client handler will still allocate a single semaphore on creation because there is special operation that have to be executed in mutex

Comment: Have you considered making that special operation synchronized?

Comment: synchronized - aside from providing mutex also fix the local thread memory visibility problem by invalidating the local cpu cache, as my operations not have this problem, using synchronize and by that invalidating the local cpu cache is a bit overhead.